# Polling / Interval from SmartGWT Client

Tags: smartgwt

I'm writing a SmartGWT application and need to execute a method on the client side every 30 seconds. In javascript I would use setInterval or setTimeout.

How do I do this in SmartGWT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with a Timer:

```
Timer t = new Timer() {
          public void run() {

             // do the callback here
          }
    };
    t.scheduleRepeating(30000); // repeat interval in milliseconds, e.g. 30000 = 30seconds
```